# How to find the stability of a series of binary sequence

Tags: statistics, probability, number-theory, coin-flipping

I am currently working on a project where I need to find the stability of multiple binary sequences of same length.

samples:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1] and [0,0,0,0,0,0] are stable
[1,0,0,1,1,0] is comparatively less stable
[1,0,1,0,1,0] is least stable
```

How to find this mathematically with some score that can be used to compare against each other and the sequence can be ranked accordingly?

Comment: Maybe the concept you are looking for is what's called "total variation"; a web search might find some resources. The answer given by Solarflare is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample evaluation, you can probably create a reasonable score by counting how often the bit value changes to the next element, normalized by the length.

E.g. something like `1/(n-1) * sum ( abs(c[i] - c[i+1]) )` as a measure for the instability from `0` (stable) to `1` (least stable, all bits alternate).

If you want the value `1` to be the most stable, use `1-1/(n-1)*...`. You may also want to define a value for lenght 1 and 0 according to your preference.